# Firebase : How to removeObserver(withHandle:) after observeSingleEvent()?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase Database with swift. I can easily remove an observer from a DatabaseReference when I observe with `databaseReference.observe(...)` :

```
databaseHandle = databaseReference.observe(
    .value, 
    with: { (snapshot) in ... }, 
    withCancel: { (error) in ... })

...

databaseReference.removeObserver(withHandle: databaseHandle)
```

My problem is when I use `databaseReference.observeSingleEvent(...)`. Because it doesn't return a *FIRDatabaseHandle*, I can't remove the observer when I want.

I know that `databaseReference.observeSingleEvent(...)` removes the observer as soon at it has been fired once. However, sometimes I need to remove the observer before it has been fired.

I also know that I could use `databaseReference.removeAllObservers()`, but this is not a convenient solution in my case.

Does one of you know how I can prematurely remove an Observer (created with  `observeSingleEvent(...)`) from a *databaseReference* ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `databaseReference.observeSingleEvent(...)` doesn't return a handle that you can remove the only option is to use `databaseReference.observe(...)`.

Just remove the handle manually once you need to **OR** when the first event fires.

### Update

Try using this extension:

```
public extension FIRDatabaseReference {

    @discardableResult
    public func observeOneEvent(of eventType: FIRDataEventType, with block: @escaping (FIRDataSnapshot) -> Swift.Void) -> FIRDatabaseHandle {

        var handle: FIRDatabaseHandle!
        handle = observe(eventType) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
            self.removeObserver(withHandle: handle)
            block(snapshot)
        }

        return handle

    }

}
```

Comment: There may be a race condition with several observers called before any handled, so I would add a boolean attribute `removed` to pre-check before removing and handling.

Comment: Yup! I agree. I am also aware that the code above might be improved in ways I didn't think of but it was just meant to give the OP an idea of how to handle this particular issue.